# Installing h2o on Anaconda 3

Tags: python, installation, anaconda, h2o

I was trying to install h2o (3.10.0.9) on Anaconda 3 in windows 10, 64 bit. The installation seemed to proceeded, and after it shows 
     "executing transaction:done"
what i got in the prompt window were a few command lines:

```
(base) C:\WINDOWS\system32>set "JAVA_HOME="  
(base) C:\WINDOWS\system32>set "JAVA_HOME_CONDA_BACKUP="  
(base) C:\WINDOWS\system32>set "JAVA_HOME=C:\Users\Xu\Anaconda3\Library"
```

And at this point, I still cannot import h2o in jupyter notebook (no module named h2o).  Note that the installation of h2o and installation of openjdk was done at the same time. I downloaded JAVA outside anaconda, and did some manual changes in the environmental variables, but it seems that this is not the problem.

Anaconda Navigator shows that h2o is installed, while h2o-py is not. Now, the problem with h2o-py is that if I install it, it will show this error:

```
UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be in conflict:    
- h2o-py    
- zict
Use "conda info <package>" to see the dependencies for each package.
```

Now, I checked all the dependencies:

```
colorama
future
patsy
python 3.5*
requests
tabulate
```

I installed future, and then tried installing tabulate, but it also shows the same UnsatisfiableError ... in conflict with zict. Then I removed zict package, and then both the installations of tabulate and h2o-py show another similar error, but this time in conflict with xlrd package. It took me too long time that I really don't want to waste any more on this.

Could anybody tell to me what I can do in order to be able to simply use h2o in anaconda? I would very much appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

Though it's too late, may be helpful for someone else.
I had the same problem and solved it by installing 'h2o' using pip command:

```
pip install h2o
```

or if you are in IPython environment:

```
!pip install h2o
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue on macOS, tried to install using `conda install -c anaconda h2o` as advised in [anaconda documentation](https://anaconda.org/anaconda/h2o) However, it did not reflect in my JupyterLab.
I finally resolved the issue by using `!pip install h2o`